# How to find specific data from a Volley Api string response

Tags: java, api, android-studio, android-volley

I am new to APIs and finally figured out how to successfully retrieve a request response from a website.  The thing is I am completely lost on how I should handle the response. I don't know how to access certain values within the response

here is my API Volley code

```
  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String uri = Uri.parse("https://chicken-coop.p.rapidapi.com/games/Fortnite?platform=pc")
            .buildUpon()
            .build().toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            displayResults.setText("Response: " + response.substring(0,500));

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             displayResults.setText( "" + error.toString());
        }

    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("X-RapidAPI-Key", "5cdb2bbe57mshd9242c8d3177cb3p16f2fbjsnd7c5829eb4ad");
            params.put("X-RapidAPI-Host", "chicken-coop.p.rapidapi.com");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Here is the response query that I received

> "result":{10 items
>   "title":"Fortnite"
>   "releaseDate":"Jul 25, 2017"
>   "description":"Epic Games next project has you building forts and stopping a zombie invasion."
>   "genre":[...
>   ]6 items
>   "image":"https://static.metacritic.com/images/products/games/5/c7eb46ceb7da9c72c5a95193e8621faf-98.jpg"
>   "score":81
>   "developer":"Epic Games"
>   "publisher":[...
>   ]1 item
>   "rating":"T"
>   "alsoAvailableOn":[6 items
>   0:
>   "iPhone/iPad"
>   1:
>   "PlayStation 3"
>   2:
>   "PlayStation 4"
>   3:
>   "Switch"
>   4:
>   "Xbox 360"
>   5:
>   "Xbox One"

How would I go about finding an **explicit value** from the **response query**? I have been searching for how to do this online and there are so many different ways to go about and I have no clue what to do. For example, how would I be able to put the **Release Date** into its own text box? Most of the examples I see online use **JsonObjects** when I m using a string response

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `onResponse` method you need to parse your result so you can extract any data you want

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
             // toaccess to your json data 
                String title = jsonArray.getString("title");
                // your code 


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks.  It isn't 1/1 what I did but you're right that I need to convert the string into a json object and go from there.  Thanks!